# Active Directory Users and Computers

Tags: ubuntu

I would like to run an Ubuntu Server 17.10 at home.  My question is, what is the Linux version of a tool that centrally runs user's and computers.  Like Microsoft's Active Directory Users and Computers?
.

Comment: You are looking for an LDAP solution.

Comment: Windows clients? SAMBA and its command line toolls.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have something like the Windows Active Directory, the solution for your problem is Samba. The Samba project has done a wonderful job in reverse engineering the Windows Active Directory and currently provides the same services as Windows, practically simulates all its features, you can even use the Windows management tools (RSAT) to manage the SAMBA server.
If you still want, here is the official site:

[Samba Project](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Main_Page)

And if you need help contact me right here to send you the guides that I have done myself.
regards...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the samba wiki under [Maintaining Unix Attributes in AD using ADUC](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Maintaining_Unix_Attributes_in_AD_using_ADUC#Curses_ADUC)
There's a curses UI for Linux that uses ldap to mimic ADUC, ADSI, etc.

Full disclosure: I'm the author.